# What is different in ram process of trigger and manual insert in mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, transactional

Which way is better for saving log of data access in table for *transactional* database ?
Using trigger or using manual insert in table?
Manual means writing sqlQuery for inserting log of program in table.

Comment: Using trigger you are sure that it will be fired (if not disabled). Manual insert could be skipped

Comment: If related to number of record access and you need to log that , If you write extra sql , you will connect to database and then perform commit for that which will be time consuming, If you write a trigger , its done in database side and you done need to connect again wchich saves some millisec :). trigger would be better pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Auditing of this kind is mostly done via triggers.** The main reasons are:

- Developers will not forget calling it, as it would happen if there is a separate insert need to be fired
- A simple bug would not cause the second insert to fail and leave the previous operation non-audited
- The auditing cannot be intentionally left out, it is really controlled by the owner of the DB
- The extra network round-trip + query parsing required by the second insert is not a small matter. For basic operations the actual time-cost of these *are* significant.

On the other hand the only downside of this solution is the extra logic that is now on DB side. By default developers tend to leave as little logic live in the DB as possible (which is normally a good idea), but in this case I think it is not a valid argument. This is *not* business logic, it is an organic part of your DB. The data about "who accessed and what data" is still data, and belongs to the database.

Comment: I ask my qustion in another way in this link  [TRIGGER or MULTI Insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252590/trigger-or-multi-insert)