# TRIGGER or MULTI Insert

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle

I think I have to ask my question in another way.
At transactional database which of the following case has been recommended:

1. writing multi or 2 insert query for saving log of program on DB that has more pressure on server .
2. writing trigger after inserting for saving log of program on DB that has more pressure on DB.

   Thanks for attention.

Comment: I think to get a meaningful answer, you need to add much more info to this question. Both of your idea can be good depending on the exact circumstances. What do you want to optimize for: speed or reliability? Is it really a high-frequency operation? Do you really need to worry about that exra pressure on the DB? What exactly are you planning to log? etc.

Comment: i want to write trigger for  saving all of my log in program inserting updating and...  . But i'm not sure that creating connection for insert statement  and making pressure on server is better or writing trigger  in DB and making pressure on it.
also for transactional DB means that many data can transaction in same time . @GergelyBacso thanks for your attention.

Comment: Oracle or MySQL?  They are quite different.

Comment: Do you want both inserts to be transactionally tied together?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the insert to the DB will happen only from your application end then I would go for the first option by creating a procedure and include both the `INSERT` statement in a `TRANSACTION` block. which will make sure atomic operation.

But, in case there are possibilities that insert to the DB may happen through adhoc query or through third party ETL tool then you have no other option than having a trigger `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` to perform the log insert operation (2nd option) since there is no way to call the other `INSERT` statement automatically or explicitly.